# Redirecting to a 404 page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a web app, and I want to redirect users to the 404 page without them actually ever going to a 404 page. Is this possible?

I added this line of code to my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

So when a user types in (a page that does not exist on my website):

```
shareit.me/jsdhjfkhoe
```

They are redirected to:

```
shareit.me/404.php
```

Is there a way to redirect to the 404 while the URL remains:

```
shareit.me/jsdhjfkhoe
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Would be nice to have one of the answers accepted as working!

Answer (score 1):

Use this to pass all paths to 404.php if they do not exist and preserve the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404.php [L]
```

Set this header in the 404.php file.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: Set the header in the non-existent page?  Why didn't I think of that!

Comment: Nobody builds (should build) websites that can have non existing pages. All pages should be passed to a few code files that will identify the page and display the content of a 404 header.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

doesn't change the URL in the client browser since it does only `internal rewrite` to `/404.php`

I suspect you have some other rule in your .htaccess doing this full redirect. If you post your full .htaccess then I can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this should do the trick:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

-> Try using an html element named 404.html in your root!

Have a look at this if you want to see a full implementation: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess

Otherwise you could have a look at the documentation if anything is unclear:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your own customized Error 404 page. Here's what you need to write down on your .htaccess.

----------- .htaccess ----------------

```
  # 1 ---- Establish a custom 404 File not Found page ----

  ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php 

  # 2 ---- Prevent directory file listing in all of your folders ----

  IndexIgnore *
```

----------- .htaccess ----------------

Where filenotfound.php is your own 404 customized page. Hope it helped.